# Media queries and device orientation change

Tags: css, media-queries, device-orientation

I've got the code below. What I would like to achieve is to switch between styles of a mobile device changes orientation from portrait to landscape (devices that have a large resolution like iPhone 4 or Galaxy S)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

    <title>KUBIK</title>
    <style>
        #mobile,
        #tablet { display: none; }

        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
            body { background-color: #FF0000; }
            #mobile { display: block; }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
            body { background-color: #00FFFF; }
            #tablet { display: block; }
        }       
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mobile">MOBILE</div>
    <div id="tablet">TABLET</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In landscape the iPhone 4 has a width of 960px, so the second rule should come in. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone has a bug when the orientation switches. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/901295) for a javascript fix

```js
// Rewritten version
// By @mathias, @cheeaun and @jdalton

(function(doc) {

    var addEvent = 'addEventListener',
        type = 'gesturestart',
        qsa = 'querySelectorAll',
        scales = [1, 1],
        meta = qsa in doc ? doc[qsa]('meta[name=viewport]') : [];

    function fix() {
        meta.content = 'width=device-width,minimum-scale=' + scales[0] + ',maximum-scale=' + scales[1];
        doc.removeEventListener(type, fix, true);
    }

    if ((meta = meta[meta.length - 1]) && addEvent in doc) {
        fix();
        scales = [.25, 1.6];
        doc[addEvent](type, fix, true);
    }

}(document));
```

Comment: this does not happen only on the iPhone, but also the Galaxy S (1st gen)