# change css on orientation change ipad

Tags: ipad, layout, screen-orientation

I am doing responsive layout with media queries and works just fine. 
When the ipad change orientation though it doesn't "refresh" the layout
accordingly to the media queries.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046152/media-queries-and-device-orientation-change ?