# CSS Media Queries not changing on device rotation

Tags: css, rotation, media-queries

If I use **max-device-width** for my media queries, when I rotate my tablet/phone the css within the media queries doesn't take effect, if I refresh the page, then the correct styles are applied.

If I change the media query to **max-width** then everything works fine on the tablet/phone but I get to see the whole responsive process on the desktop, which I don't want.

Im using the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

And my media queries are:

```
@media screen and (max-width:800px)
{
}
etc......
```

I've tried the following:

- Adjusting the values, 799px to 801px
- Stacking max-width, followed by max-device-width
- Changing the meta tag to only include device width

Nothing seems to work apart from max-width

How can I get the media queries to take effect without showing the responsive process on the desktop?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a browser issue? IE, the browser is simply not re-rendering the page when it is rotated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046152/ ?

Comment: I thought the CSS inside the media queries meant that the page simply changes it's layout.

Everything works fine if I change the media query to max-width, other than it displays the responsive site on the desktop which is not wanted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best way but you could copy your css code and have one copy inside the @media screen brackets and the other copy outside of it.
e.g.

.css code for desktop{

}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){

```
.css code for phone/tablets etc{

}
```

}

The desktop code can be exactly the same as the media code only not nested within the @media screen brackets. It is extra code but it should ensure your desktops open the way you want them to without effecting your other media devices and vice-versa.